# Django Signals for time period

Tags: django

I'm going to implement questionnaire application using django. Each page consist of 4 questions. Now how can i implement time for each page. Suppose each page has 30 min how can i implement this for my questionnaire application.

Comment: This is not what signals are for.

Comment: Is there any way to implement this using django signals?

Comment: This is not what signals are for.

Comment: Some other way. Preferably one that can deal with time.

Answer (score 1):

You want to limit time, that person can spend for this test?
In this case you should display timer using javascript and have additional check at server-side: save timestamp and id of this test attempt and validate them when page is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be handled on the server, not completely at least. Most of it has to be done in javascript. Either just having the timer that calls a javascript function when the time is up, or polling the server for the timeout though AJAX.